# Extra parentheses in C

Tags: c

In C++, in some contexts, parentheses might change the meaning of the enclosed expression (for the given context). For example, decltype(expr) and decltype((expr)) often yeld different types:

```
int x;
decltype(x) a=x; // type int; a initialized with a copy of x
decltype((x)) b=x;//type int&; b is a reference to  x; extra parentheses matter!
```

But what about C?

Enclosing macro parameters into parentheses is a common practice in C, can that produce some unexpected side effects?

[edit ]More precisely, if the parentheses are redundant for grouping, may they change program meaning?

I consider only expressions (not other syntactic elements such types, functions parameters lists, etc).

Comment: Consider `1+2*3` and `(1+2)*3`

Comment: I don't think the wording `side effect` is appropiate here.

Comment: @David: I'm not about grouping, of course :)

Comment: BTW: if the `()` would **not** change the meaning of the expression they could be omitted. IOW: the question is not very clear: what exactly do you mean by `side effect` ?

Comment: @wildplasser: Ok, I had some doubts with this term, title changed

Comment: @wildplasser: I added some clarifications..

Comment: Perhaps you should supply some examples. It's rather vague.

Comment: I noticed that. I'm still thinking. I cannot find an example of extra `()` changing the _meaning_ of an expression (apart from precedence/associativity/grouping, obviously). `sizeof arrayname` comes to mind, but that is explictely excepted by the standard from arrayname being degraded to a pointer-expression, even with excessive parentheses.

Comment: @David I may supply only C++ examples, because I don't know any C examples - it is the reason for the question :)

Comment: I mean examples to indicate what you are excluding from the question. I gave you an example, but you said that it did not count. So, tell us precisely what does not count in your eyes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think he intends to write header files that can be included by both C and C++, and fears that there might be some hidden semantics for excessive parentheses in C. (I don't think there are)

Comment: @wildplasser I'd like the question to be clear so that we don't have to try to interpret it. I'd like there to be no need for "I *think*" comments.

Comment: @wildplasser: yes, I'm about extra parentheses (redundant for grouping). So the answer is "No"?

Comment: Here is some simple examples of misuse [link](http://www.c4learn.com/errors-mistakes-misuse-of-c.html)

Comment: I guess the QA means cases where additional `()` are used in C++ to avoid either pointer decay or function pointer decay might apply. from what I know C in itself is consistent there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is "No".

I'm not aware of any cases where adding an extra pair of unnecessary parentheses, as in `((blah))`, would change the meaning. As you say, this is critical for most macro definitions.

However, there are various cases where explicit grouping can causes changes not related to the rules of maths. I'm not referring to `(1+2)*3`; that's just math. I mean something where the compiler ends up producing a different, but equivalent, code sequence that is more, or perhaps less, efficient.

For example, consider this function;

```
float fourth_power (float n) {
  return n*n*n*n;
}
```

It can perform differently to this function:

```
float fourth_power (float n) {
  return (n*n)*(n*n);
}
```

In pure maths the results should be the same, but in reality with finite sized float values, you can get a different numerical answer, but that's not what I'm talking about here.

The change I'm talking about is that the second form *runs faster*. If you know you're only using smallish numbers (where the limits of float are not an issue) then you might like to code it the second way for a speed boost.

In fact, GCC will make this transformation if you use `-ffast-math`, I think, but ordinarily the compiler will play it safe.

This is one example that probably applies to all compilers (because it has to do with numerical accuracy), but there are many examples where apparently arbitrary grouping decisions can take a particular compiler down a different internal decision path, and can have interesting, and measurable differences in performance, code size, etc.

Comment: I hope you are right and I'll probably accept your answer if no disproof follows... As for grouping, it may affect not only speed, but also precision, and your notes are worthy (though not addressing the question directly)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
#define SIMPLE_USELESS_MACRO(X) (X)

int int_ = 2;
long int long_int_ = 2L;
double double_ = 3.14;

double result = long_int_ + SIMPLE_USELESS_MACRO(int_ + double_);
```

if I'm right, in case when parentheses are around x the conversion sequence is following:

(assuming there is no compiler optimalization)

1) int -> double
2) long int -> double

in case there are no parentheses the conversion sequence is:

1) int -> long int
2) long int -> double

I'm not sure about time of above conversions, but probably the integer->float conversion takes more time (assuming there are no hardware unit responsible for this).

This is just a suggestion, if I'm wrong sorry.

Comment: The parentheses in your example change grouping and the order of operations, so they aren't redundant. I asked (the qustion perhaps is too vague, so my apologies) about "extra" parenthesis that don't change evaluation order, but may possibly change something else and yeld a different result (I added C++ example to the question)

Comment: Yes, you are right and I completely agree with you.
I just wanted to show, that in this particular example, when the result of the operation is same (because of alternation of adding) the existence (or not) of parentheses can cause some additional effects.
Anyway, now I understand you were asking for something else :-)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
#define ODD( n ) n % 2

int a = 2;
bool n1 = ODD( a + 1 ); // a + 2 % 2
bool n2 = ODD( (a+1) ); // (a + 2) % 2

n1 true (!=0)
n2 false (==0)
```

Comment: not exactly, in your example parentheses change grouping and operations order, I'm rather about redundant parentheses that do not change grouping. I added C++ example and ask for something similar in C (my apologies for, perhaps, vague question, I failed to explain it better)

Comment: then no, macros are just dumb text substitutes.